# The End of Time, Wilfred and the Woman

Tags: doctor-who

I was wondering if anyone had any theories as to why the "Woman" told Wilfred to not tell the doctor anything about the conversations she had with him??

I don't see how this would have altered his decision either way.

Comment: Are we sure it's a dupe? I don't actually see an answer to this question on that one.

Comment: @MacCooper But we don't know anything about the woman, neither about her origin nor about her motives etc. So this question would get no better answers than the other one.

Comment: @MrLister, true, true :) ignore me haha XD